# How to call canvas from another function?

Tags: kotlin, parameters

I am struggling with this problem
I have for example this code

```
 val itemSwipe = object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT), DialogFragmentNoticias.DialogFragmentDismissListener {
        override fun onMove(
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        ): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onChildDraw(c: Canvas, recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, dX: Float, dY: Float, actionState: Int, isCurrentlyActive: Boolean) {

            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, 0f, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);

        }

        override fun getMovementFlags(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Int {
        }

        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {



        }

        override fun DialogNoticiasDismiss() {
          
            viewHol?.let {
                adapter.notifyItemChanged(it)
               
                allowed = true
            }
        }

    }
```

I have extended an interface to make a listener, and what I am looking for is use the parameters like c:Canvas or viewHolder:RecyclerView.ViewHolder
in this function listener

```
     override fun DialogNoticiasDismiss() {

        viewHol?.let {
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(it)

            allowed = true
        }
    }
```

How do I manage to do this? Any ideas will help a lot

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why don't you just pass those variables as parameters to the function like you do for the other methods of the DialogFragmentDismissListener interface (which I assume is something you control)?

Comment: Because these functions are generated by themselve when I extended from ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT), So I don't really know how they get those parameter